# Couldn't resize project sidebar is doom emacs

Tags: treemacs, doom

I'm using [doom](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs) emacs.

I've enabled `treemacs` in `~/.doom.d/init.el`

[image: init.el]

[image]

I couldn't resize the project sidebar. I have tried this mac OS and opensuse 15.1

I get message `<left-fringe> <mouse-drag-1> is undefined`. Do I miss any configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add these lines to my doom config in order to allow resizing via mouse to work:

```
(setq treemacs-width 30)
(setq treemacs--width-is-locked nil)
(setq treemacs-width-is-initially-locked nil)
```

Answer (score 5):

Either set treemacs-width explicitly by adding something like `(setq treemacs-width 30)` to `~/.doom.d/config.el`

Otherwise press `tw` to toggle fixed-width mode in treemacs, then you can resize it.

Adding `(setq treemacs--width-is-locked nil)` to `~/.doom.d/config.el` may work too